# sympy : expression simplification

Tags: python, sympy

I begin with sympy python lib.

If, I have this expression

```
from sympy.abc import a,b,c,p,q
e = p * ( a + b ) + q * ( a + c )
```

how I can use `a,b,c` as factor ? like

```
a(p+q) + b*p + c*q
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from sympy.abc import a,b,c,p,q
from sympy import collect, expand
e = p * ( a + b ) + q * ( a + c )

print e
print expand(e)
print collect(expand(e),a)
```

Answer (score 3):

`collect` is indeed the function you want. You can pass multiple symbols as the collection variable to collect them all.  And as you noticed, `collect` will not expand your expression first, so if you want that, you have to do it yourself with `expand`.

```
In [15]: collect(e.expand(), [a, b, c])
Out[15]: a⋅(p + q) + b⋅p + c⋅q
```